# Jersey 2.9 set resource-lifecyle per-session

Tags: rest, xmlhttprequest, jersey

I have a web-application where I need to have one instance of my resource per session.

I tried to follow the example given here, replacing the PerSessionRessource part with my own class

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html

However it seems like the Provider is not used, at least I can see that I'm acessing a new instance of my resource class with my second request.

I try to register it within the application as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        System.out.println("Registering the application");
        register(PerSessionComponentProvider.class);


        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(HttpSessionFactory.class).to(HttpSession.class);
                bind(SessionInjectResolver.class)
                .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<SessionInject>>(){})
                .in(Singleton.class);

        }
    }

            );
}
```

How can I make sure that I access the same instance of my resource with every httprequest from a client. In Jersey 1.x there seems to have been the @PerSession annotation, how can I get this functionality in Jersey 2.x?

Thanks in advance!